# python program produces same output regarless of input

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python program that reads a binary file every minute containing live stock market data by accepting their names as command line arguments and writes their content to a database table. However, it seems to produce the same output for every file regardless of its content which should not be the case since every file has different values. What can i do get rid of this problem?

Thanks and Regards. Heres my code:

```
import struct as st
import pymysql
import sys
import os

os.chdir(r'/root/IND')
print("FILE TO BE OPENED:",sys.argv[1]+".ind")
fName=sys.argv[1]+".ind"
print("you want to open",fName)

mkt = open(fName, "rb")
print("Opened",fName)

transcode=5
mlength=78
i=0

while(i<46):
 #HEADER DATA

 transcode = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(2), byteorder='little')

 timestamp = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 mlength = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(2), byteorder='little')

#BODY DATA

 indtok = str(int.from_bytes(mkt.read(2), byteorder='little'))
 print("Token:                                                                ------------------------",indtok)

 iov = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 civ = str(int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little'))
 print("Value:",civ)

 hiv = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 liv = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 pc = str(int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little'))
 print("Percentage change:",pc)

 ihiv = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 iliv = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 ioiv = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 iciv = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 filler = int.from_bytes(mkt.read(4), byteorder='little')

 #print(i,"--NEXT FILE")
 i+=1
```

Comment: Please, show us the code.

Comment: hi Vaclav, could you help me now?

Comment: I can't see the problem. Have u solved it? @Vedant7